# Node Js Mongoose requesting input value gets undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add an edit button to my blog, Firstly I Have a post request `/edit` on the edit button, then it sends you to another page, where It automatically fills with the database content.

Finally, I have another post request for editing the file. I did it a couple times, it didn't work, so I console logged it, the values that I was getting were undefined.

```
app.post('/edit', (req,res)=>{
const editId = req.body.editBtn;
Blogdata.findOne({_id: editId}, (err, dataFound)=>{
    // res.render('edit', {data: dataFound})
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        res.render('edit', {data:dataFound})
    }
})
})
```

this sends you to the ejs edit file

```
<%- include("partials/head") %> 

<form action="/editDone" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group-login">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="tit" id="title" value="<%= data.title %> ">
</div>
<div class="form-group-login">
    <label for="desc">Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="des"  id="desc" value="<%= data.description %> ">
</div>
<div class="form-group-login">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" class="fileForm" value="<%= data.img %> ">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn-form-login" name="btnIdd" value="<%=data._id %>">Submit</button>
```

Then finally, when you click the submit button here, it does another post requesting `findoneandupdate`,

```
app.post('/editDone', (req,res)=>{
const newTitle = req.body.tit;
const newDesc = req.body.des;
const newFile = req.body.myFile;
const edit2Id = req.body.btnIdd;
console.log(newTitle)

Blogdata.findOneAndUpdate({_id: edit2Id}, {title: newTitle, description: newDesc, img: newFile}, (err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log("failed to update")
    }else{
        console.log("Updated Successfully")
    }
})
})
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the actual database to see if the changes has been committed ? In order to get the updated data in response, you should use findOneAndUpdate like this:

```
result = await findOneAndUpdate(
{ _id: edit2Id },
{ title: newTitle, description: newDesc, ..etc },
{ new: true }
)
```

Notice the third field, it causes mongo to return updated document instead of old document. The way you're doing is fine as well but remember, You won't get the updated document in return even though your changes has been committed to DB

Comment: The problem is, when I console logged newTitle in the last part, I got undefined. same with all of the other inputs. couldn't get them. I don't know what the reason is

Comment: are you using this middleware ?
```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: Yeah I am, I only have problem with this specific post request. The others are doing fine in my code.